# XML Parsed Image OnClick

Tags: android, xml, parsing, imageview

Hi i have parsed a online xml containing images, I got stuck on parsing the images onclick if anyone knows the answer can you please help?

```
public class SingleMenuItem  extends Activity {

// XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "song";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.libraryonclick);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent
    String song = in.getStringExtra(KEY_SONG);
    String artist = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ARTIST);
    final String thumb_url = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblSong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView lblArtist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    ImageView lblThumb_Url = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.onclickthumb);


    Button link3Btn = (Button)findViewById( R.id.button1 );
    link3Btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
    {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(thumb_url);
        startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );
    }
    });

    lblSong.setText(song);
    lblArtist.setText(artist);
    lblThumb_Url.setSrc(thumb_url);
```

Thankyou i know it has something to do with the line above started coding it but got stuck

```
Main Activity
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/48258247/music.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.library);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
        map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
    }


    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Click event for single list row


    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String song = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
            String artist = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist)).getText().toString();
            String thumb_url = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(CustomizedListView.this, com.example.androidhive.SingleMenuItem.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_SONG, song);
            in.putExtra(KEY_ARTIST, artist);
            in.putExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL, thumb_url);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });     
}
```

Comment: Are you getting URL for iamges??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is your code for the button functionality inside the on create method?

```
 public void onClick(View v)
 {
     Uri uri = Uri.parse(thumb_url);
     startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );
 }
```

I have a feeling that this placement is outside the scope of the actual onclick event. transfer the on click function out of the onCreate method at first, so your program can actually do something on the onClick call.

Are you parsing local uris or uris from the internet? You cannot access local resources straight from the uris, you have to use a content provider. That might also be the problem, but can't really say without seeing more code.